# Automatic Google Sheets Back Up without Copying the Forms attached to the Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I make a script that copies a Google Sheet as a backup into a backup folder in the Google Drive, but not making copies of the Google Forms that are attached to the Sheet?

```
function backUp() {
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
    var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNhZESRq_0_DVBwzA8fvxSYGMpOa6KC_");
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

    file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

This one automatically copies the original files into the Backup Folder, but it also copies the Google Forms that are linked to it... so I end up with 10+ copies every day after it saves.

Comment: What happens if you unlink the said Forms?

Comment: I need to have the forms linked because the forms and sheets will be actively used by the club. I just need to back up the data inside the sheets in case any of them gets deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. It was little hard for my knowledge, I catch it :)

Is unable to copy whole Spreadsheet without Form, because they are *magically connected* (magically ==> connection is under any public API possibilities).

You can take to use the `copy sheet to another spreadsheed` feature.

I tried it and it doesn't create copy of Form, yeah!

But for this case have Script & Drive unwieldy API. Result looks too hacky:

```
function backUp() {
    //Open old spreadsheet
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    //Prepare new name
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
    var name = spreadsheet.getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;

    //Prepare file system objects
    var oldfile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNhZESRq_0_DVBwzA8fvxSYGMpOa6KC_");

    //create new spreadsheet
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);

    //move to destination folder (yep, it's hacky)
    var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
    var parents = newFile.getParents();
    while (parents.hasNext()) {
        var parent = parents.next();
        parent.removeFile(newFile); //remove from default folder
    }
    destination.addFile(newFile);

    //copy all sheets to new spreadsheet
    var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
        sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
    });

    //remove empty sheet (created with new spreadsheet)
    newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and also do you know how to get all the sheets inside? The current script only makes back up of the first sheet in the spreadsheet. Is there a way to make the script count how many sheets are in a spreadsheet and automatically make copies of all of the sheets inside, instead of manually setting the number of sheets?

Comment: @user9853395 I changed Script in previous response. Try it.

Comment: Do you know any ways to keep the sheets from changing names? The spreadsheets should change their name to indicate that they are backups, but I want the sheets to be named as they are. For instance, right now, the script makes the sheets named "Copy of (the name of the sheet)". But Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Change `sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);` to `sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName(sheet.getName());`