# Copying sheets using appscript pulls through forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that pulls the ID of a file within a specific folder, then takes a copy and puts that into another folder then deletes it from the original folder.

However when the takes a copy it then copies any attached google forms and places them in the folder also.

Is there a way to only copy the sheet?

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copies")
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID'); //Latest Copy ID
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);

  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var archive = DriveApp.getFolderById("ARCHIVE_ID"); // Backup Folder 
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(value);

  var name = file.getName();

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, archive);
file.setTrashed(true);  //  sets the file in the trash of the user's Drive
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

All files in your folder are found and processed, you're not checking for a specific file type.

---

#### Modifications:

Check the file type before you write to the array.

```
if (file.getMimeType() === 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet') {
  var row = [];
  row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize());
  list.push(row);
}
```

---

#### Reference:

- [`getMimeType()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getMimeType())

Comment: This is still giving the same issue. The folder only ever has one google sheet in the folder. No other file types exist. But when the copy is made, it seems to create copies of forms too which are in different locations within Drive.

Comment: Hmm - just tested this myself and it looks like if you have any linked forms, those are copied too. What if we just loop through the folder after the copy has been made and trash the form?

Comment: Alternatively - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549311/automatic-google-sheets-back-up-without-copying-the-forms-attached-to-the-sheets), which uses APIs to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ross

Comment: I just ran through the folder and trashed the two forms after moving making the copy. Thanks again